# Extracting json fields in a log line using awk or some other cli tool

Tags: command-line, string, json

Here's the log format in the system that we are currently using and right now it's not easy to change the logs format through the entire system. And I need a way to extract the json object in the logs and its fields. So that I can have easier time looking at the logs as currently the size of the messages is too big.

This is the log formate

```
A B C {"field name one":value of field , "msg": "a sample message", "c": c}
```

Here's a sample log. Note that the fields A, B, C don't have spaces but the json object's fields and values may have spaces.

```
service_name/syslog.log:2022-09-24T16:18:01.38754199Z stdout F {"level":"info","ts":1664036281.3874626,"msg":"system sample message","host":"host_name","processor":"test","reqId":"1234"}
```

and through cli, I'd just want to print the values in msg. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

`jq` is a common tool to manipulate JSON.  `jq -r .msg` will return the decoded value of the `msg` key in the JSON document.

You can use `cut` to get the JSON data by extracting the fields from field four onwards (`cut -d ' ' -f 4-`)

So combine them:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 4- | jq -r .msg
```

eg

```
echo '2022-09-24T16:18:01.38754199Z stdout F {"level":"info","ts":1664036281.3874626,"msg":"system sample message","host":"host_name","processor":"test","reqId":"1234"}' | cut -d ' ' -f 4- | jq -r .msg
system sample message
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
$ jq -r -R 'sub("[^{]*"; "") | fromjson.msg' file
system sample message
```

This uses `jq` to read the input as a set of "raw" text lines. The text of each line is trimmed to remove anything before the first `{`.  The remainder of the text is then converted into a JSON object using `fromjson`, and the object's `msg` value is extracted.